# Classical vs Modified Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

How do you show that the classical and modified Gram-Schmidt orthogonolization are mathematically equivalent. I presume a rigorous proof is not necessary, but conceptually how could this be explained. Thanks!

Comment: What are the "classical" and "modified" Gram-Schmidt respectively?

Comment: Looks like a [decent reference](https://www.math.uci.edu/~ttrogdon/105A/html/Lecture23.html) on the modified version.